# XFCE Always Open Certain Types of Windows on the Same Workspace

Tags: xfce, workspaces

Is there a way in XFCE to ensure that every time a certain type of window opens, it goes to a specified workspace? For instance, every time a ffplay window opens, I would like it to open on workspace 4, no matter what the active workspace is.